# くゆえて or くめえて word-request

Tags: words, word-requests

[image]This is my first time asking a question so I'm pretty excited! Thanks a lot in advance for taking your time to read my rant.
At the moment I'm working on a translation, but I'm having problems with a word that's hard to define because it's hand written.
This is the phrase:
彼がくゆえていた部分
But when I look for "Kuyuete" meaning, even if I split the word in two, I didn't found any meaning. It seems I have three totally useless japanese dictionary's because I didn't found anything at all.
So I tried with: "Kumeete" but I didn't have luck neither.
Have you heard about those words? I've been looking for it about 1 week.
Thanks a lot!

Edit: I added the image text, it seems the real word is "**くめえて**" instead "くゆえて" and finally after a loong research I think "汲む" it's the word I'm looking for.

Comment: くわえる？ くらえる？ A picture would help.

Comment: I could kinda guess already, but It would be a far better question if you provided more context.

Comment: @oals What would 彼がくらえていた部分 mean?

Comment: Nothing useful I hope, I just added it because the sounds fit.

Comment: please provide a picture, your guesses so far don't make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to answer. I've already upload the image.

Comment: No, 汲む is definitely not the word you're looking for. (What form is 汲めえていた supposed to be anyway?) Rather than spending long hours searching for a word that doesn't exist, your time might have been better spent learning about (handwritten) *hiragana* that would have allowed you to identify the character as わ (and not め or ゆ).

Comment: You're right, there was no way I could suspect the syllable was わ after all. Thanks a lot and I'll take your advise! I'm a bit ashamed because as you said I was troubled about the form, but still wanted to ask you even if looked like a fool instead don't get the real answer. 
I'm very grateful, thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb you are looking for is 「く**わ**える」, which means "***to hold between one's teeth***".

(This has nothing to do with 「加{くわ}える」 ("to add").)

「くわえていた部分{ぶぶん}」 means "the part (someone) was holding between his teeth"

「く**め**えて」 makes no sense.

「汲{く}む」("to dip up") does not conjugate to 「くわえていた」.  It can only conjugate to 「く**んで**いた」.